# Exploding struct type large number of columns to two columns of keys and values in Pyspark

Tags: python, struct, pyspark, explode

I have a pyspark df who's schema looks like this

```
 root
 |-- company: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 0: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 1: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 10: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 100: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 101: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 102: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 103: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 104: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 105: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 106: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 107: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 108: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- 109: long(nullable = true)
```

I want the final format of this dataframe to look like this

```
id    value
0     1001
1     1002
10    1004
100   1005
101   1007
102   1008
```

Please help me to solve this using Pyspark.

Comment: can you provide he code to recreate the input dataframe so we dont have to do that and focus on the problem. See how to create a [minimal, complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's a Json file and I have created dataframe directly from it

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

> Written in scala but should be achieved in pyspark with minimal changes

### Load the test data

```scala
    val df = spark.sql("select company from values (named_struct('0', 'foo', '1', 'bar')) T(company)")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----------+
      * |company   |
      * +----------+
      * |[foo, bar]|
      * +----------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- company: struct (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- 0: string (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- 1: string (nullable = false)
      */
```

### Explode struct

```scala
    val structCols = df.schema("company").dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].map(_.name)
    df.withColumn("company", map_from_arrays(
      array(structCols.map(lit): _*),
      array(structCols.map(c => col(s"company.$c")): _*)
    ))
      .selectExpr("explode(company) as (id, name)")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+----+
      * |id |name|
      * +---+----+
      * |0  |foo |
      * |1  |bar |
      * +---+----+
      */
```

Comment: But in the question you mentioned its of string type. Check your schema in the question

Comment: Updated the Question and some of the functions are not available in Pyspark

Answer (score 0):

In python you can convert it using stack

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from functools import reduce
df1 = df.select('company.*')
cols = ','.join([f"'{i[0]}',`{i[1]}`" for i in zip(df1.columns,df1.columns)])


df1 = reduce(lambda df, c: df.withColumn(c, f.col(c).cast('string')), df1.columns, df1)

df1.select(f.expr(f'''stack({len(df1.columns)},{cols}) as (id, name)''')).show()

+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  0| foo|
|  1| bar|
+---+----+
```

Comment: company.* i.e. struct columns are of LongType not able to convert all columns to String Type in Pyspark